# How to get a user's PayPal account using the PayPal API?

Tags: paypal

My application needs to pay some users regularly and automatically via PayPal.

I'm planning to do this using Adaptive Payments APIs. To use the API I need to know the user's PayPal account.

Of course I can simply ask the user for his account name, but without validation it's quite possible that he will make a typo or some other mistake and his money will end  up in someone else's account.

So, I'd like - ideally - for the user to go to PayPal, authorize there, and let PayPal return me his authenticated account ID.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PayPal Access will do what you want: https://www.x.com/developers/x.commerce/products/paypal-access

Comment: Hey thanks, I'm off that project now, but hope this helps someone.

Comment: This link doesn't work anymore, any alternative?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it the way an automated gasoline pump, or Paypal itself, does it: Try to authorize for a $1 charge, or a very small credit (2 cents or so).

If it works, you can then pass along the full charge.